# Conditional probability for a sum of two Poisson random variables

Tags: probability

Let X and Y be independent random variable each Poisson distributed with common parameter $\lambda$. Find the conditional probability $$P(Y=y|X+Y=z) \text{ for } y=0,1,...,z.$$

my method is: 
let 
$Z=X+Y$ and $X1=X$ ,after finding the joint pdf of $Z$ and $X$, $f_{X Z}(x,z)=\frac{\lambda^{2x+2y}\times e^{-2y}}{x!(x+y)!}$, and i will know the marginal PDF of $Z$,
but I am stuck here, I dont know how to do this,$f_{Z}(z)=\int^z_0\frac{\lambda^{2x+2y}\times e^{-2y}}{x!(x+y)!}dx$, or is there another method to solve this question?

Comment: You're confusing discrete and continuous variables. Here you want have integrals, just sums. Try to prove first that $Z\simeq \mathrm{Poisson}(2\lambda)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the definition of conditional probability and independence of $X$ and $Y$:
$$\begin{align}
P(Y=y\mid X+Y=z) &=
\frac{P(Y=y \text{ and }X+Y=z)}{P(X+Y=z)} \\[1ex] &=
\frac{P(Y=y \text{ and }Y=z-x)}{P(X+Y=z)} \\[1ex] &=
\frac{P(Y=y)\times P(Y=z-x)}{P(X+Y=z)} && \text{because, independence}
\end{align}$$
Now use the fact that $X+Y$ will be a Poisson r.v. with mean $2\lambda$:
$$
P(Y=y|X+Y=z)=
\frac{(\lambda^x e^{-\lambda}/x!) \times (\lambda^{z-x} e^{-\lambda}/(z-x)!)}{2^z\lambda^z e^{-2\lambda}/z!}.
$$

Comment: PS: If you don't already 'know' that fact, you can show it via, $$\mathsf P(Z=z) ~=~ \sum_{k=0}^z \mathsf P(X=k)~\mathsf P(Y=z-k)$$ (PPS: Don't forget the binomial expansion, $(1+1)^z = \sum_{k=0}^z \binom{z}{k}$)

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2978826/potential-typo-and-independence-between-two-random-variables-that-are-related-v