# Potential typo, and independence between two random variables that are related via a sum

Tags: random-variables, independence, poisson-distribution, conditional-probability

My question is based on this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2127011/conditional-probability-for-a-sum-of-two-poisson-random-variables). In the question, $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables that follow a poisson distribution, and $Z = X + Y$. This is the math in question:
\begin{align}
P(Y=y\mid X+Y=z) &=
\frac{P(Y=y \text{ and }X+Y=z)}{P(X+Y=z)} \\[1ex] &=
\frac{P(Y=y \text{ and }Y=z-x)}{P(X+Y=z)} \\[1ex] &=
\frac{P(Y=y)\times P(Y=z-x)}{P(X+Y=z)} && \text{because, independence}
\end{align}

I have two questions:

(1) $P(Y=y \text{ and }X+Y=z)$ in the numerator was changed to $P(Y=y \text{ and }Y=z-x)$. I'm not sure how one can change $X$ to $x$, since I would imagine $P(Y=y \text{ and }Y=z-X)$ is the right step, since $X$ is a random variable, not a constant like $x$. Is that a typo?

(2) If what I said above is correct, are we claiming independence because of the memoryless nature of the Poisson distribution?

Comment: The answer in the earlier post seems to be wrong. What you find in the  answer below is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should be

\begin{align}
P(Y=y\mid X+Y=z) &=
\frac{P(Y=y \text{ and }X+Y=z)}{P(X+Y=z)} \\[1ex] &=
\frac{P(Y=y \text{ and }X=z-y)}{P(X+Y=z)} \\[1ex] &=
\frac{P(Y=y)\times P(X=z-y)}{P(X+Y=z)} && \text{because, independence}
\end{align}

They are independent because we are told that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.